# Jest test not running sequentially

Tags: node.js, jestjs, integration-testing

I would like to run my test in the below order:

```
Test1.test.js
Test2.test.js
Test3.test.js
Test4.test.js
```

But each run I'm getting different order, please find my files and config below - could you please help what am I missing here?

**My folder structure**

```
my-app/
├─ node_modules/
├─ tests/integration
│  ├─ Test1.test.js
│  ├─ Test2.test.js
│  ├─ Test3.test.js
│  ├─ Test4.test.js
├─ jest.config.js
├─ package.json
├─ package-lock.json
```

**Test1.test.js**

```
describe("Test-1", () => {
    test("Run Test-1", async () => {
    });

});
```

**Note: I've similar code for Test2.test.js and so on.**

**jest.config.js**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    testMatch: [
        '**/integration/*.test.js'
    ]
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "com.test.jest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest -i"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^26.6.3"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "asdf"
}
```

I tried below option too but no luck :(

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --runInBand"
  }
```

**Test Output:**

```
 PASS  tests/integration/Test1.test.js
 PASS  tests/integration/Test4.test.js
 PASS  tests/integration/Test2.test.js
 PASS  tests/integration/Test3.test.js
```

My expected order for each run is below one but I'm not getting in this order

```
 PASS  tests/integration/Test1.test.js
 PASS  tests/integration/Test2.test.js
 PASS  tests/integration/Test3.test.js
 PASS  tests/integration/Test4.test.js
```

It would be really appreciated if someone can help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: The answer of steventle in this link(https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/619) might help you.

Comment: I would avoid this dependency as your tests them seem to depend on something that a previous test set up or changed. Part of the beauty of Jest is running tests in parallel for speed. Also, isolated tests makes it easier to change and understand what your tests are doing, since the tests now have dependencies that will be harder to maintain over time as your code changes.  If it is testing data, then you can have separate files/functions, and then include the shared code via import statements.